# How can I make a text from a pdf to split into multiple chunks(PDFBox and Java ).? I have also an error

Tags: java, maven, pdfbox

I'm trying to save some information from a Cv in PDF format into some variables using Java and Maven. I will put the code below.

**PDFBoxReadFromFile.java**

```
package pdfboxreadfromfile;

import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.PDRectangle;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author Felix
 */
public class PDFBoxReadFromFile {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        PDFManager pdfManager = new PDFManager();
        PDDocument doc = null;
        doc = new PDDocument();
        PDPage page = new PDPage();
        doc.addPage(page);
        PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page);

        PDFont pdfFont = PDType1Font.TIMES_ROMAN;
        float fontSize = 25;
        float leading = 1.5f * fontSize;

        PDRectangle mediabox = page.getMediaBox();
        float margin = 72;
        float width = mediabox.getWidth() - 2*margin;
        float startX = mediabox.getLowerLeftX() + margin;
        float startY = mediabox.getUpperRightY() - margin;


        pdfManager.setFilePath("src\\main\\resources\\pdfs/CV.pdf");
        try {
            String text = pdfManager.toText();
            List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
            int lastSpace = -1;
            while (text.length() > 0)
            {
                int spaceIndex = text.indexOf(' ', lastSpace + 1);
                if (spaceIndex < 0)
                    spaceIndex = text.length();
                String subString = text.substring(0, spaceIndex);
                float size = fontSize * pdfFont.getStringWidth(subString) / 1000;
                System.out.printf("'%s' - %f of %f\n", subString, size, width);
                if (size > width)
                {
                    if (lastSpace < 0)
                        lastSpace = spaceIndex;
                    subString = text.substring(0, lastSpace);
                    lines.add(subString);
                    text = text.substring(lastSpace).trim();
                    System.out.printf("'%s' is line\n", subString);
                    lastSpace = -1;
                }
                else if (spaceIndex == text.length())
                {
                    lines.add(text);
                    System.out.printf("'%s' is line\n", text);
                    text = "";
                }
                else
                {
                    lastSpace = spaceIndex;
                }
            }

            contentStream.beginText();
            contentStream.setFont(pdfFont, fontSize);
            contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount(startX, startY);
            for (String line: lines)
            {
                contentStream.drawString(line);
                contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount(0, -leading);
            }
            contentStream.endText();
            contentStream.close();

            doc.save("break-long-string.pdf");



        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(PDFBoxReadFromFile.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (doc != null)
            {
                doc.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**PDFManager.java**

```
package pdfboxreadfromfile;

/**
 *
 * @author Felix
 */

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.io.RandomAccessFile;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper;

public class PDFManager {

    private PDFParser parser;
    private PDFTextStripper pdfStripper;
    private PDDocument pdDoc;
    private COSDocument cosDoc;

    private String Text;
    private String filePath;
    private File file;

    public PDFManager() {

    }

    public String toText() throws IOException {
        this.pdfStripper = null;
        this.pdDoc = null;
        this.cosDoc = null;

        file = new File(filePath);
        parser = new PDFParser(new RandomAccessFile(file, "r")); // update for PDFBox V 2.0

        parser.parse();
        cosDoc = parser.getDocument();
        pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
        pdDoc = new PDDocument(cosDoc);
        pdDoc.getNumberOfPages();
        pdfStripper.setStartPage(0);
        pdfStripper.setEndPage(pdDoc.getNumberOfPages());
        Text = pdfStripper.getText(pdDoc);
        return Text;
    }

    public void setFilePath(String filePath) {
        this.filePath = filePath;
    }

    public PDDocument getPdDoc() {
        return pdDoc;
    }


}
```

I tried the code above and I have the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: U+000D ('controlCR') is not available in this font Times-Roman encoding: WinAnsiEncoding

I want for example to store the name from the cv person in a variable and to read it.

Comment: You attempt to draw a string that contains a Carriage Return (U+000D) control character. There are no glyphs for control characters. Thus, `drawString` fails.

Comment: This is somewhat a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34553148/